# pyautogui - Xlib.error.BadValue

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using the pyautogui library, and it was working...and for some reason after I reinstalled my Ubuntu system I dont manage to use it.

I show below the code, just several lines copied from the Docs.
The only information about the error, showed in picture I found is this link mentioning "BadValue error", which I dont really understand (100 and 200 are inside range)
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)
pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.click(100, 200)
```

Thanks a lot!

[Picture with code and execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mswQw.png)

Comment: Any help? I cannot solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why this error is coming, because in PyCharm, it works perfectly. But I noticed that the first 3 lines are unnecessary so try this code and tell me if it helps:

```
from pyautogui import *

click(100, 200)
```